# document.style.backgroundImage - How to have DIV without content show full background image

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-manipulation

I need to add in a full width banner on a specific page on a WordPress website so I figured DOM Manipulation would be the way to go...

The banner, is just an image. Nothing else.

The only way, so far, that I can get the image to show is to put in some content using innerHTML...

Is there another way to get an empty div with a background image to just be the size of the background image?

```
const websiteNav = document.getElementById("nav");
    
const banner = document.createElement("div");
    
banner.innerHTML = '<br>';
banner.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://www.website.com/images/image.png')";

websiteBanner.appendChild(banner);
```

Comment: No, CSS doesn't know the size of a background image. However, an `<img>` tag does. If it's just the image, why not use that?

Comment: Just place an `img` into the div and if you need to have text or other items on top of that image, use CSS.

Comment: I did try: 

banner.innerHTML = '<img src="https://www.website.com/images/image.png">'; but the div doesn't show at all.

Comment: That should work. Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Sidenote: my personal opinion would be to modify the PHP file which houses the `nav` element and put your HTML there.

Comment: banner.innerHTML = '<img src="website.com/images/image.png">'; does work now. Must of been some kind of user error on my part when I tried a while ago. Now to use CSS to try and make this look good... I understand what you mean about modifying the PHP file however, they want this on just one page. So, that is why I thought DOM manipulation would be the best route?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier forgot to tag you in my previous comment. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. You're still able to add this on a single page with PHP, but it depends on how the templates are set up. If it's part of the page template, then you could either make a `page-{name}.php` or `template-{name}.php`. Otherwise I assume the `header.php` should be modified with a conditional statement checking if the current page is the page you're trying to modify.